# WebStorm navigate to Angular directive with dependencies not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 8.0.4 and when I have a module of the type:

```
var module = angular.module('myModule');
module.directive('myDirective', function() {

    return {

        templateUrl: 'XXX.html',
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});
```

It works fine when Ctrl + clicking on the element within WebStorm, such as:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

But not when the directive includes dependencies such as:

```
var module = angular.module('myModule');
module.directive('myDirective', ["$scope", function($scope) {

    return {

        templateUrl: 'XXX.html',
        restrict: 'E'
    };
}]);
```

Anybody encountering the same issue?

Comment: You're missing the injection: `module.directive('myDirective', ["$scope", function($scope) {` ... maybe this will help.

Comment: @OmriAharon - Its a mistake when placing my question as in Angular, it was correct.  I updated the question with the correct syntax, yet the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try upgrading - [WEB-13091](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13091) is fixed in WebStorm 9